# IPhone UIImageView Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to set image to UIImageView programmatically but it does't work. I have following code.

```
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self localImagePath:NO]]];
```

and

```
-(NSString *)localImagePath:(BOOL)forSave {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSPicturesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *picturesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *picturesPath = [picturesDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
    if (forSave || [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:picturesPath]) {
        return picturesPath;
    }
    else {
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
    }
}
```

Is it possible to set image to UIImageView on run time from different mediums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `imageNamed:` method takes only the filename as an argument, not a path. Also it will look for that file in the main bundle only. Try using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

Comment: I tried your and it worked for the half test. I still need to do full test. Are you sure the function "imageWithContentsOfFile" will work for images from pictures directory?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use two different ways to load the image

`[UIImage imageNamed: name]` for the resource based one

`[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filename]` for the one you found locally.

consider changing your method to return the `UIImage` and use the appropriate loading method internally.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self localImagePath:NO]]`, instead of `[UIImage imageNamed:...]` for the one you found using your localImagePath method.